# I am trying to run the following code in Xilinx but i am encountering multiple errors

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am trying to run the following code in Xilinx but I am encountering          multiple errors.

Code :

```
Library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use work.rng.all;

entity mutation is
    port(
        mut:in std_logic;
        pop_size:in integer range 0 to 15:=10;
        mem_mutated,bits_mutated:out arr
        );
end mutation;

architecture Behavioral of mutation is
begin
    process(mut)
        Variable s1,s4:integer:=1 ;
        Variable s2:integer range 0 to 15;
        Variable s3:integer range 0 to 1000:=5;
        variable s5:integer range 0 to 1000:= 8;
        variable ind_no, bit_mut:integer;
        variable mut_ind, bit_pos:arr;
    begin
        s2:= pop_size;
        if mut=’1’ then
            for i in 1 to mut_bits loop
                randg(s1,s2,s3,ind_no);
                mut_ind(i):=ind_no;
                s3:= s3+ 2;
                randg(s1,s5,s4,bit_mut);
                bit_pos(i):= bit_mut;
                s4:=s4 + 1;
            end loop;
            mem_mutated<= mut_ind;
            bits_mutated<= bit_pos;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Below are the errors from the running the code:

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:104 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 6: Cannot find
>    in library . Please ensure that the library was compiled,
>   and that a library and a use clause are present in the VHDL file.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 9:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 7: Unit  ignored due to previous errors.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:374 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 11: Entity  is not yet compiled.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 14:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 15:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 16:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 17:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 18:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 19:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 21:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 23:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 24:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 25:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 26:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 27:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 28:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 29:  is not declared.
>       ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 31:  is not declared.

What can I do to eliminate these errors?

Comment: impossible to understand which program you are using. However, normally it is enough to re-install again your program

Answer (score 2):

firstly `use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;` <= don't use that.

Then error by error

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:104 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 6: Cannot find <rng> in library <work>. Please ensure that the library was compiled, and that a library and a use clause are present in the VHDL file.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 24: <randg> is not declared.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 27: <randg> is not declared.
```

^ Apparently you have not compiled `rng` yet. Or you switched libraries. You cannot instantiate a non-existing component.

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 9: <arr> is not declared.
```

^ The output of the entity `mutation` is of the type `arr`, but what is this type? Where is it defined?

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 7: Unit <mutation> ignored due to previous errors.

ERROR:HDLCompiler:374 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 11: Entity <mutation> is not yet compiled.
```

^ Too many errors to continue...

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 14: <integer> is not declared.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 15: <integer> is not declared.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 16: <integer> is not declared.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 17: <integer> is not declared.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 18: <integer> is not declared.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 21: <s2> is not declared.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 26: <s3> is not declared.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 29: <s4> is not declared.
```

^ These occur due to earlier errors. They will go if the others are fixed.

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 23: <mut_bits> is not declared.
```

^ just what the error says: `mut_bits` is not declared anywhere.

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 25: <mut_ind> is not declared.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 28: <bit_pos> is not declared.
```

^ as `arr` is unknown, `mut_ind` and `bit_pos` cannot be declared.

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:\mutation\mutation.vhd" Line 31: <mem_mutated> is not declared.
```

^ `mem_mutated` is an input port of the component, but no signal is defined.